# Expectation of $\beta_0$ for OLS when conditional expectation of error term is a non-zero constant

Tags: statistics, least-squares

Given a regression model $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + u_i$. Least squares assumptions are fulfilled, except that E($u_i | X_i = x$) = 10 in this case. Is it correct to say that $\hat\beta_0$ is an unbiased estimator of ($\beta_0 + 10$)?

My working:
$$\hat\beta_0 = \bar{Y} - \hat\beta_1\bar{x} $$
$$\bar{Y}=\beta_0+\beta_1\bar{x}+\bar{u}$$
$$\hat\beta_0 = \beta_0+\beta_1\bar{x}+\bar{u} - \hat\beta_1\bar{x} $$
$$= \beta_0+(\beta_1-\hat\beta_1)\bar{x}+\bar{u}$$
$$E(\hat\beta_0|x)=E(\beta_0|x)+E(\bar{x}(\beta_1-\hat\beta_1)|x)+E(\bar{u}|x)$$
$$E(\hat\beta_0|x)=\beta_0+\bar{x}E[(\beta_1-\hat\beta_1)|x]+E(\bar{u}|x)$$
$$E(\hat\beta_0|x)=\beta_0+\bar{x}[\beta_1-E(\hat\beta_1|x)]+E(\bar{u}|x)$$
Here I'm not sure if $E(\hat\beta_1|x)$ is still equal to $\beta_1$, assuming it is:
$$E(\hat\beta_0|x)=\beta_0+\bar{x}[\beta_1-\beta_1]+E(\bar{u}|x)$$
$$E(\hat\beta_0|x)=\beta_0+E(\bar{u}|x)$$
$$E(\hat\beta_0|x)=\beta_0+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(u_i|x)$$
$$E(\hat\beta_0|x)=\beta_0+\frac{1}{n}(10n)$$
$$E(E(\hat\beta_0|x))=E(\beta_0+10)$$
$$E(\hat\beta_0)=\beta_0+10$$

Comment: Yes. You can regard the expectation of noise as a component of $\beta_0$.